# how to access javascript array in descending(reverse) order?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

```
var content1    =  eval ("(" + data + ")");
var content    =  content1.Data;  
for (property in content) {console.log(content[property].name); }
```

I need to access this content array descending order. now it's work fine but not the way I want.It print first element in the array.

I want to print last element in first place. MySQL gives descending order result set but this for loop print first id element in first place.

Comment: If it is an array then you shouldn't be using `for..in` in the first place. Use a conventional `for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++)` to loop forwards, and then make the obvious changes to loop backwards. Or `content.reverse().forEach(...)` or `content.slice().reverse().forEach()`...

Comment: Also, can you please explain why you are using `eval` in this context?

Comment: because this array has php objects. one array location including one object. for (property in content) {console.log(content[property].name,content[property].address); }

Comment: Why can't you use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()`?

Comment: yes i can use JSON.parse() . so how can it help my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can either do from reverse length.

or

You can just `reverse()` the array

```js
var array = [1,2,3];

for (var item of array.reverse())
{
  console.log(item);
}

console.log(" ");


var other = ["first", "second", "third"];

for (var i = other.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  console.log(other[i]);
}
```